# Big BIG hard drive problem - Safe to power off? - Need help ASAP!

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ubuntu-mate

I woke up today to see my computer acting a bit strangely. Brightness being stuck, stuff like that. Anyway, **everything** is now read-only, most importantly resulting in being unable to mount an external hard drive and the Disks utility claims 3992 bad sectors, which was 0 last time I checked. SMART data claims the drive is OK.

What should I do? If I reboot the computer, could that risk putting my files in limbo? Most files can go but some I don't have backed-up.

Please give advice quickly.

Ubuntu MATE 16.04 x64

**EDIT:** Also, I'd be willing to take recommendations for replacement hard drives (UK).

**EDIT 2:** I forgot to mention that it's a laptop and was working fine last night. Well, the ethernet wasn't. Not sure if that's linked or not. Let me know if there's any further information I can provide which may help.

**EDIT 3:** I'm going to bite the bullet and reboot. See if this changes anything.

EDIT 4: See my comment in response to heynnema.

Comment: Please explain in more detail. Which drive has 3992 bad sectors, and how did you get that information. You won't be able to mount an external drive if the primary drive is read-only. SMART says which drive is OK? Pretend you're the reader, and ask yourself, do I understand the (little) information provided?

Comment: The computer's hard drive is the one in question. The information was obtained from the "Disks" utility, as stated. SMART claims the 3992 bad sectors drive is OK. Anyway, the system would no longer boot so I used a live DVD to make a disk image and copy everything off. The bad sector count upped to over 4000 but has since dipped to 3984 due to remapping. All is well. I ought to replace the drive (without damaging the ribbon cable above it somehow) at some point but for now it's running fine. 5MB unreadable so there's surprisingly little damage for the number of system files missing.